# 10-pin IC marking ON=4J 728 identification

Tags: power, integrated-circuit, identification, converter

Please help me identify this IC. I can't find anything on any websites about it.

Four capacitors above it had been shorted.

[image: 4 capacitors above it had been shorted]

---

[image: photo of PCB]

This board is inside the 5 GHz RF transmitter.  I think this is the power IC for the amplifier part of this board.

Comment: Doesn't look like a silicon ic package. More likely some sort of inductance/coil/ transformer device

Comment: Can you provide more info of the kind of board it's on ? What its nearby components are all about ?

Comment: This board is inside the 5GHz RF transmitter.  I think this is the power ic for amplifier part of this board.

Comment: @SongLinh - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it wasn't the answer to your original question. It was additional info, so it has been added to your question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. || Since you asked the question, unless you are writing the *full & final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself & don't need further help) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, to add more information / clarification, please [edit] the question. Or comment to respond to a minor point. || Please see the [tour] & [help] for more rules. Thanks.

Comment: @SongLinh - Hi, To try to avoid any misinformation: You said: "*Four capacitors above it had been shorted.*" That is very unlikely. If those capacitors are across power rails there are other, more likely, explanations. Did you remove them from the PCB after taking the photos and then measure them? Or did you measure them "in circuit"? Please [edit] your question to explain how you know those capacitors are shorted. Thanks.

Comment: I measure them in circuit, and i find it's shorted. After that, i remove the 4 capacitor to measure each capacitor, they're good. But I measure in the position where capacitor soldering, it's still shorted. So I think that this IC is failure.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Richtek RT6150AGQW](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT6150A=RT6150B/DS6150AB-04.pdf) Buck-Boost Converter. The Product code marking is 0N=.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/DC-DC-Converters_Richtek-Tech-RT6150AGQW_C147971.html))